# Prevent Iframe reloading on post back

Tags: iframe, postback, reload

I have a webpage with one iframe and a button.

On Page Load event,

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
string sDocUrl = //some doucmen url
Iframe1.Attributes["src"] = sDocUrl;
}
```

When the page is reloaded (by clicking a button), this iframe is being
reloaded too. This iframe has a static data and doesn't need to be
reloaded everytime when I click a button. Is there a way to prevent
iframe to be reloaded when webform is reloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a page is reloaded, any iframes contained in it (just as any scrips, images, anything) will always be reloaded. There's no working around that, sorry, simply because the *entire page* actually reloads.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the iframe dynamically using JavaScript:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    $('#foo').append('<iframe src="' + sDocUrl + '"></iframe>');
}
```

That uses jQuery to add the iframe to an element with an id of "foo".  But it will only add the iframe if the expression in the 'if' statement returns true.

Comment: Although on second glance at your question it seems you still want to have the iframe displayed on postback right?  If thats the case then @d is correct, there is no way to prevent it from reloading.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right, it needs to be there after post back too.  Thanks for your help.